# filling missing indices in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fill out the missing indices with 0. I've tried some code from similar questions, but it didn't really do the trick fully.

I have a DataFrame:

```
df
2    1
5    5
```

When I use: `df.reindex(range(df.index[0], df.index[-1] + 1), fill_value=0)`, I get:

```
df
2    1
3    0
4    0    
5    5
```

I expect:

```
df
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0    
5    5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `reindex` with `np.arange`:

```
>>> df.reindex(np.arange(df.index[-1] + 1), fill_value=0)
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    5
dtype: int64
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for reminding me of `fill_value` ;) normal `range` should do

Comment: @timgeb Ah, yeah, that's true. Yeah `fill_value` is very handy with `reindex` :)

Comment: Just for information, @timgeb is right, use `range` instead of `np.arange` because `range` is converted to `pd.RangeIndex` rather than `np.arange` is converted to `Int64Index`. There is no big difference except memory consumption for large dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
df.reindex(range(df.index.max() + 1), fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

After `np.arange` and `range`, the last version with `pd.RangeIndex`:

```
>>> df.reindex(pd.RangeIndex(df.index.max()+1), fill_value=0)
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    5
dtype: int64
```